# how can i update a table column with another table column based on another based off 2 other columns

Tags: php, mysql

Hey guys how's it going?

Ok so i'm having trouble writing a small script and i can't seem to understand what its not working my reasoning is:

update all the tech_kunena_messages.subject with tech_kunena_topics.subjects where tech_kunena_messages.thread and tech_kunena_topics.id are the same...

the script i've come up with is this:

```
 $con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass) or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_selectdb($db,$con) or die(mysql_error());

    mysql_query("UPDATE tech_kunena_messages 
        SET tech_kunena_messages.subject=tech_kunena_topics.subject
      FROM tech_kunena_messages 
      JOIN  tech_kunena_topics ON tech_kunena_messages.thread = tech_kunena_topics.id");
    echo "Done Pease check the data base";
    mysql_close($con);
    ?>
```

But for some reason tech_kunena_messages.subject is not getting updated with any thing, this is like my third time writing a script and i don't have the reflex to see what is wrong for me it should work ( i also tried with INNER JOIN but nothing happend either oh the code is beeing read as when i navigate to the scripte i get the please check the database..

any ideas?

Thanks guys

Alex

Comment: update with join syntax is doubt full put error checking

Comment: UPDATE TableA SET Column1 = (SELECT Column2 FROM TableB WHERE TableB.SomeColumn = TableA.AnotherColumn)

Comment: The UPDATE with an INNER JOIN syntax works fine on SQL Server, but it's not ANSI Standard.

Comment: yeah i need to get the reflex to create error checks in every thing i write thanks guys much appreciate the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `UPDATE` query should look like below

```
UPDATE tech_kunena_messages tkm              
      JOIN  tech_kunena_topics tkt
   ON tkm.thread = tkt.id
SET tkm.subject= tkt.subject
```

Comment: Awsome thanks, I'm guessing the tkm and  is just for reference for below i don't actually need to put them in or is that a short cut? ha damn newbies ^^